# SQL task select top N records where in is a variable from a parameter?

Tags: ssis

Ive got another task elsewhere in a package that I build a sql command from a script task, but I now have a simpler sql task that I want to parameterize the number of records I fetch, and drive this parameter via a package variable.

Now:

```
SELECT TOP 10 col1,col2,col3 from TABLE-A
```

What I need to use
eg.  `SELECT TOP ? col1,col2,col3 from TABLE-A`

Where ? corresponds to a package variable of type int.

Can I do this with just the SQL task, and not have to derive the statement in something like a script task first?

[ update ]
Solution is what I was suspecting, I just added another script task before the sql task, and generate the statement there.  Then change the sql task to use the variable that contains the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the variable to build a dynamic sql string in a separate variable, and then execute the dynamic sql string variable.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters can only be used in the WHERE clause.

As Tab mentioned, you will need to create a variable expression to construct the SQL statement. Then, in the Execute SQL Task, you will tell it to use a SQL String (see bullet point 4 in the section "Map query parameters to variables").

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2017#parameters-in-the-execute-sql-task

Comment: Actually you can use them in the select clause also to populate a variable value as output.  However, it seems you cant use parameters with a TOP criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @intVal as int = 5
select * from
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Id) as RowNo, * from <tableName>
)a
where a.RowNo <= @intVal
```

here @intVal will be parameter should be mapped in SQL task